# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core with Code First approach but receive following error when trying to start application:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint 'FK_Grades_Students_StudentId' on table 'Grades' may cause
>   cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not
>   create constraint or index. See previous errors.'

My entities:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Group Group { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects { get; set; } = new List<Subject>();


}

public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Grade> Grades { get; set; } = new List<Grade>();

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]

    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }

}

public class Grade
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfGettingGrade { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubjectId")]

    public Subject Subject { get; set; }

    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]

    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
}


modelBuilder.Entity("GradeBook.Core.Models.Grade", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("GradeBook.Core.Models.Student", "Student")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("StudentId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                b.HasOne("GradeBook.Core.Models.Subject", "Subject")
                    .WithMany("Grades")
                    .HasForeignKey("SubjectId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an unnecessary foreign key on `Grade`. `Grade` references `Subject` and `Subject` references `Student`. So referencing `Student` from `Grade` when `Subject` also references `Student` creates a redundant path. Remove `Student` from either `Grade` or `Subject`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for multiple cascade paths is that you can get from `Grade` to `Subject` in 2 ways - either `Grade -> Student -> Subject` or the direct connection `Grade -> Subject`. You have to remove one of the references, and my suggestion is to go for removing the connection between `Student` and `Subject` tables. Use the `Grades` table as the Many-To-Many relations table.